# Check if Foreign Key is used; if not -> delete

Tags: python, django

I have a Model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4000)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1,related_name="Author")
```

now, if i want to delete an author i need the system check if that pk is not used as FK in another model.

```
def delete_author(request, pk)
    auth = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=pk)
    ### here must check if is erasable before delete
    auth.delete()
    return render(request, '...')
```

For example I have 2 Author: John and Mike and 1 book: Simple_book writed by John

Author Mike can be erasable, John no

Can someone help me?

Comment: `on_delete=models.PROTECT` in your foreign key would enforce this constraint

Comment: That is exactly what the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) is for.

Comment: @IainShelvington perfect, it work! But it give django error, how can i render a popup?